# Elixir script does not complete

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

I tried to implement FizzBuzz in elixir. I *think* it works, but I have some weird behavior and it may be my environment. I can run the following `.exs` file using `elixir fizzbuzz.exs` and on the first run it works as you would expect. Even on the second run it would work as you would expect. However, if I wait 7 or 8 seconds and run it again, it will stop at 13, or maybe 14. It might even make it to 50. There really isn't anything too consistent about what I am experiencing. I've reproduced it on the first run, I've reproduced it after waiting two seconds between runs. I've even gone a few minutes without being able to reproduce it at all. Please help me...

```
IO.puts "Hello world from Elixir"

defmodule Fizzbuzz do
  def run(max) do
    run(1, max)
  end

  def run(n, max) do
    if rem(n, 3) == 0 do
      IO.puts "FIZZ"
    end

    if rem(n, 5) == 0 do
      IO.puts "BUZZ"
    end

    if rem(n, 3) != 0 && rem(n, 5) != 0 do
      IO.puts n
    end

    if n < max do
      run(n + 1, max)
    end
  end
end

Fizzbuzz.run(100)
```

[image: evidence]

```
#: Elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.2] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1]

Elixir 1.9.4 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 20)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the weird behaviour. As you say: must be something specific in your environment.

Comment: I'm hoping to be given some pointers on how to debug my environment

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue outside VSCode, in a regular terminal?

Comment: yes, I can reproduce it inside or outside of vscode in command prompt, powershell, and git bash

Comment: I have elixir installed via Chocolatey, and I plan on, later today, uninstalling it via chocolatey and installing it as via the web installer.

Comment: Weird. I'd guess the program is producing the output, but the lines are somehow not flushed to the terminal before the program ends. You could try adding a `:timer.sleep(1000)` after `Fizzbuzz.run`, to see if something like that is going on.

Comment: @PawełObrok Looks like you may be on to something. After adding `:timer.sleep(1000)` to the end of the script I am no longer able to reproduce my problem. I didn't like the pause at the end so I changed the value for sleep/1 to `200` and I am still unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: wow an odd situation. have you tried using `asdf` version manager? or `IEx.configure(inspect: [limit: :infinity])`?

Answer (score 1):

First, try updating to the latest release of Elixir, `1.13`, currently.

Try running your file with `mix run <filename>`, so in your case:

```
mix run fizzbuzz.exs
```